# Quitar elementos de un array en un fichero en python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
array = ['info@aireconsultores.es','integralfitstore@gmail.com','info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com']
```

y luego tengo un fichero de texto con lo siguiente:

```
info@aireconsultores.es
integralfitstore@gmail.com
info@jamonesdeseroncheca.com
ertsol1@lubrial2000.com
contact@ytcvn.com
info@centroro.es
```

como podria quitar los elementos en el fichero de texto de mi array es decir para que quede el fichero de la siguiente manera:

```
ertsol1@lubrial2000.com
contact@ytcvn.com
info@centroro.es
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una forma sencilla sería procesar línea a línea tu fichero de entrada y verificar para cada línea si ese dato está en tu array, y *si no está* escribirlo en otro fichero de salida.

Así:

```
with open("entrada.txt", "r") as f_in, open("salida.txt", "w") as f_out:
   for linea in f_in:
       if linea.strip() not in array:
           f_out.write(linea)
```

Lo de `linea.strip()` es para eliminarle los espacios que pudiera tener en el fichero por delante o por detrás, así como el retorno de carro, antes de compararlo con los elementos del array.